# CSS using position of parent div for positioning

Tags: css, sass

I have 3 divs nested inside of one another. For the 3rd nested div, I want the position to be based on the parents div, not the grandparent div. I'm confused because I thought that that's how it always worked, that the absolute position was based of the parent container. Here is what I have now:

```
     #expandedView
     {
       width: 96vw;
       height: 20vh;
       padding: 4vw;

       #descriptionContainer
       {
         height: 10vh;
         width: 100%;

         #descriptionIcon
         {
           position: absolute;
           top: 0px;
           left: 0px;
           width: 1vh;
           height: 1vh;
         }
       }
     }
```

And for the HTML:

```
 <div id="expandedView">
    <div id="descriptionContainer">
       <div id="descriptionIcon">

       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to it's closest positioned (or non-`static` positioned) ancestor.

So to position `#descriptionIcon` relative to `#descriptionContainer`, add `position: relative;` to `#descriptionContainer`

```css
#expandedView {
  width: 96vw;
  height: 20vh;
  padding: 4vw;
  background: blue;
}
#expandedView #descriptionContainer {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
#expandedView #descriptionContainer #descriptionIcon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 1vh;
  height: 1vh;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="expandedView">
  <div id="descriptionContainer">
    <div id="descriptionIcon">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it had to be non-static. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SamMcC np. Yeah if all of the absolutely positioned element's ancestors are statically positioned, the absolutely positioned element will be positioned relative to `body`